# How to format the php code to blade format

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'am new to blade templating. how to convert the blow complex php code to laravel blade template structure

```
<?php foreach($multiticheckbox as $key => $newrow){ ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo ucfirst($key); ?></td>
    <?php
    foreach($newrow as $j => $chkboxes ){  ?>
      <?php
      foreach($chkboxes as $k => $item ){  ?>
              <td>
                <?php
                    $checked="";
                    if(sizeof($access_relation)){
                        $checked = (isset($access_relation[$j][$k]))? 'checked':'';
                    }
                ?>
                <input <?php echo $checked; ?> class="child_chkbox"  type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $item; ?>" name="group_module_access[<?php echo $j;?>][<?php echo $k;?>]"></td>
        <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>
</tr>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

```
@foreach($multiticheckbox as $key => $newrow) 
<tr>
    <td>{{ ucfirst($key) }}</td>
    @foreach($newrow as $j => $chkboxes ) 
      @foreach($chkboxes as $k => $item ) 
              <td>                                                       
                    @if(sizeof($access_relation) )
                        @php
                        $checked = (isset($access_relation[$j][$k]))? 'checked':'';
                        @endphp
                    @endif                                                         
                <input {{ $checked }} class="child_chkbox"  type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $item; ?>" name="group_module_access[{{$j}}][{{ $k}}]"></td>
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
</tr>@endforeach
```